# Properties of one form

Tags: differential-geometry

If we define a tensor $R_a (X,Y)=a(X)Y+a(Y)X+g(X,Y)a^\sharp$, where a is a one form and $g(a^\sharp, X)=a(X)$, what is $R_1$, is that a Riemannian curvature tensor?

Comment: Certainly not a curvature tensor: Your $R$ is _symmetric_ in $X$ and $Y$, not skew-symmetric.

Comment: What do you mean by $R_1$, there is no $R_1$ in your expression.

Comment: I mean when $a=1$.

Comment: What do you mean by $1(X)$ and $1^#$ ?

Comment: That is what I want to know..it was not clear to me what $R_1$ means and I found it in a form of a question. So, you think it does not make any sense?